# Website migration issues?

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting, domain-name

**Background**:

So I have a website which is up and running. But now I want to change the hosting provider of my existing website due to certain issues.

Since, I am changing my hosting provider I thought I had do some website changes as well so I am going to buy a new WordPress theme from a third-party and run it on the new hosting provider.

**My research**

For what I learned, I will have to buy a different domain name and host my newly bought WordPress theme on it. And when I have made the desired changes to my WordPress theme then I can change the domain settings with my new hosting provider and redirect the old website links to the new website.

**My question is**

How can I host my new website on the same domain while my old website is still hosted? Is that even possible?

Is there a way where I can keep my existing website running while I am working on my new website but the new website needs to run on the same domain name as the old website was running on?

Comment: `the new website needs to run on the same domain name as the old website was running on` : why?

Comment: Because it's a unique domain name and I don't want to change it.

Comment: you understand me wrong: why you want your development site to have the same domain as your working one? just use some subdomain, after finishing migrate it where you need

Comment: Oh, my bad. Just to clarify can I use any random domain name and do all my development on it and once I have a final website I can migrate it to my old domain by simply redirecting it? Is that what you are implying?

Comment: something like, you even can not redirect it, but replace the old website with new one( add add redirect rules for old urls in the new website )

Comment: I want redirects due to SEO rankings.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you 3 solutions to solve this problem depending on your ability.

1. On live site running you login hosting and create new site dev after done you can point domain to new hosting and move code ( use plugin i think point domain + souce about 1 - 2h if update delay can 1 day ), if you are anxious you can temporarily turn off the indexing.
2. New hosting provider when payment done they'll send you link static domain temporary ( or use domain free: tk, co.cc,... ) and you working it after done you need point domain and update url in database.
3. Old hosting provider you can create new subdomain but point it to new hosting provider and working in new hosting when done you only point main domain to new hosting after use plugin clone to root site.

Can use DNS but you need you need to have experience with the system.
Hope to help you solve your problem.

Note:
You can learn plugin [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) best migration hosting.

Comment: So in solution 2, you are implying that I can use a different domain name rather than use the existing domain name I have? And then once I have completed the website changes I can point the domain name back to my original domain name?

Comment: It's static domain temporary eg 123.123.131.13/user/temporary
After you done on new hosting provider you can point domain to new hosting provider then update url in database WP ( before we use url temporary ).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do.

1. Create a full backup of your exiting files and database
2. Activate the maintainance mode
3. Install your new theme into your current wordpress installation
4. Make the required changes
5. Once you are happy get a full back up including database
6. Do the DNS changes on your domain register
7. Upload your site, to your new host , to the correct path / folder
8. Wait for the DNS update and your are good to go.

Comment: Thank you but which domain and hosting am I using in this case?

Because, I need to change my hosting provider.

Comment: above 1- 5 to be done inside your existing hosting provider, using the same existing domain.

Comment: I don't have cpanel access to the existing hosting provider. That's why I am moving towards a different one.

Comment: do the backup via wp-admin.

Comment: Well, the existing website is not on WordPress and I don't have the cpanel access. The current website is created on a customized platform and not WordPress.